# Is Intel Anti-Theft Technology available for individuals?

Tags: security

From looking at [Intel's page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150731014723/http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/anti-theft/anti-theft-general-technology.html) about anti-theft technology, I can't really figure out if this services can be used by individuals. My feeling is that big corporations are the only target of this product.

To be a little more specific, is there anybody that is actually using this service who doesn't work for a big corporation?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything on that page to suggest it can't be used by an individual. The page has links to find laptops and service providers that support Intel AT.

Comment: Yep, I followed a few of those links and ended up with nothing so that's I think it's designed for corporations.

Comment: @Pawel, Intel doesn't actually provide you with the tools to use the technology (at least not yet), they just make the technology. Other companies will produce the tools you use with it. Also worth noting, wrapping a laptop in tin foil defeats this anti-theft technology; also removing the battery, or the 3G Modem, stealing it in a place with no 3G coverage (harder than the previous methods, but still plausible)... The technology interesting, but pretty far from fail-safe.

Comment: Doesn't this also depend on WPBT, meaning you'd also have to use a non-Microsoft operating system to prevent the OS from installing a firmware-stored executable which phones home as well?